# Jmeter: I want to run test plan with dynamic thread number

Tags: multithreading, dynamic, jmeter

I want to generate report (number of user(number of thread)/response time). I want to use dynamic number of thread . How can I do it?
Or if you have other solution, please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can define number of threads using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(threads,)}` and override the value using [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jthreads=100 -n -t test.jmx -l results.jtl
   ```
2. You can add threads when your test is running using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and Groovy language like:

   ```
   ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread(0,ctx.getEngine()) // to add a new thread


   ctx.getThreadGroup().stopThread('thread name', false) - to stop a running thread
   ```

   where `ctx` is a shorthand to [JMeterContextService](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html) class instance
3. You can use [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) combination. Throughput Shaping timer has [`load_profile`](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing) property so you can define a very custom workload logic and you can set up a [feedback loop](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) between the Constant Throughput Timer and the Concurrency Thread Group so JMeter could kick off new threads in order to reach the target requests per second rate. You can install both test elements using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).

Comment: I set Throughput Shaping Timer : Start RPS and End RPS (1: 2). And Concurrency Thread Group with Target Concurrency : 2 , Ramp up time : 4, step count : 2. I expected there are 4 successful requests and responses but it is error at 4th request . What is happened? Can you help me to explain, please?